# How to create a PUT method to update a user

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, webstorm

Trying to update a user in my database from my website. Below you can see the code that I've used to get data from my database and that works correctly, but I can't update data in the database from the input fields of the html.component(MySQL)

settings.component.ts

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  settings = {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/user';

  ngOnInit() {
    //Get data from baseUrl(variable above url to the backend)
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
      .subscribe(
        val => {
          const usernameField = val;
          // @ts-ignore
          const usernameNaam = JSON.stringify(usernameField[usernameField.length - 1].username);
          console.log(usernameField);
          console.log(usernameField[0].username);
          this.settings.username = usernameNaam.slice(1, usernameNaam.length - 1);
        }
      );

    this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
      .subscribe(
        val => {
          const emailField = val;
          // @ts-ignore
          const emailNaam = JSON.stringify(emailField[emailField.length - 1].email);
          console.log(emailField);
          console.log(emailField[0].email);
          this.settings.email = emailNaam.slice(1, emailNaam.length - 1);
        }
      );

    this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
      .subscribe(
        val => {
          const passwordField = val;
          // @ts-ignore
          const passwordNaam = JSON.stringify(passwordField[passwordField.length - 1].password);
          console.log(passwordField);
          console.log(passwordField[0].password);
          this.settings.password = passwordNaam;
          this.settings.password = passwordNaam.slice(1, passwordNaam.length - 1);
        }
      );

    this.http.put(this.baseUrl, this.settings.username)
      .subscribe(
        val => {

        }
      );

}
}
```

This is from the backend:

```
 /**
     * Updates individual user
     * @param user
     * @return updated user
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response update(User user){
        repositoryService.update(user);
        return Response
                .status(200)
                .entity(user)
                .build();
    }
```

Can someone help me with the correct PUT method that I have to use to get data from my database.

Comment: ideally your `put` request should expect a query param as `id` what's your endpoint expects?

Comment: https://arian-celina.com/implementing-rest-services-in-angularjs-using-restangular/

Comment: Added the endpoint expectation above @Aravind

Comment: Do you have a value in **this.settings.username** when you make POST request?
It seems to me that you don't have it in time when you send post request because it starts before getting data from get request.

Comment: The get method is getting data from my database @srjkaa

Comment: @ÖmerUyar yeah, exactly! But on the client-side (in your angular application) your get method return data after that moment when you send **post** request - by this reason with **post** method you send in **this.settings.username** this field value 'undefined'.
If you want I can try to change your code, you will paste it in your application and see the result.

Comment: I am open for everything if you have some ideas for the PUT, I am ready for it :) @srjkaa

Comment: What are these `usernameNaam = JSON.stringify(usernameField[usernameField.length - 1].username);` for? What does the JSON look like that you get back from get user?

Comment: Also, GET _does_ work, or does not: "_code that I've used to get data from my database and that works correctly, but I can't get data from my database_"?

Comment: Yes thank you, I changed it in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
  .subscribe(
    val => {
      const usernameField = val;
      // @ts-ignore
      const usernameNaam = JSON.stringify(usernameField[usernameField.length - 1].username);
      console.log(usernameField);
      console.log(usernameField[0].username);
      this.settings.username = usernameNaam.slice(1, usernameNaam.length - 1);

      this.http.put(this.baseUrl, this.settings.username)
        .subscribe(
          val => {
            console.log(val);
          }
        );
    }
  );
```

It is the simplest one which you can try (but it's a bad practice to make asyncronous operation inside .subscribe()).

Comment: HTML component for username below:
<code>
<form>
                <ol class="field-list" style="list-style-type:none">
                  <li class="text-break">
                      <label>Username:</label>
                      <input value="{{settings.username}}">
                  </li>
              <button
                  type="submit"
                  class="btn btn-outline-success float-right"
                >Save</button>
</form>
</code>
Where exactly can I add something in this html to activate the PUT method in the GET method that you've posted?

Comment: In code which you are posted above your **get** and **post** method's placed in **ngOnInit** hook. Do you see result in the console after post method completed?

Comment: It is getting the username, email and password (from the database) from the user in the input field, but what I want further is the user to be able to change his data from the input fields and then click on save to send it to the database.